# PHP file in WAMP isn't accepting any value from html's GET or POST methods

Tags: php, html, forms, wamp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<body>
<form action="testrun.php" method="GET">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and testrun.php is

```
<html>
<body>
Welcome: <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the output i'm getting after typing 'xyz' in Name and 'xyz@abc' in Email text box:

Welcome

Your email address is:

NOTE: i have enabled 'rewrite_module' in Apache>Apache Modules>

I'm struck with this and donno where the problem might be. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s)  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Are all services running and running properly? Use `!empty()` for your arrays in a conditional statement.

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML code of the result page?

Comment: Note to *potential* future answers and some existing ones: **Read and UNDERSTAND the question FULLY before submitting an answer**.

Comment: To the moderators. This person posted a misleading question and it should be deleted. The OP never bothered checking back in comments and answers given, which were all misread. Since you won't let me reflag this, think again and read the question/answers next time you disagree; you were wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You have to change the method of getting the `mail` field like this:

```
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>
```

Because you are using the `GET` method for your form.

2) Maybe your WAMP server is not running PHP. Put this in your `body` to make sure it's working:

```
<?php echo "PHP is working !" ?>
```

3) Try starting WAMP as administrator, or restart WAMP (or even your computer, just in case)

Comment: The `$_GET` should work for the name though - and it doesn't.

Comment: Point #1, re-read the question. Points #2-3, yeah that's something that needs to be checked. That's not my downvote btw (edit: they retracted it). You misread the question in regards to point #1 *"1) You have to change the methode of getting the mail field like this"*

Answer (score -1):

Your method is a GET

```
<form action="testrun.php" method="GET">
```

and trying to return a POST

Change to:

```
<?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>
```

Comment: The `$_GET` should work for the name though - and it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Try to give a name and value to the input submit button.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
```

Use a get method for email like `$_GET['email']`

Answer (score -1):

Try declaring the variables name and email on your testrun.php file i.e

```
<?php $name = $_GET["name"]; $email = $_GET["email"]; .....*rest of the code* ? >
```

Also, decide whether you are going to use POST or GET. From your form,  you are using method get. Use the same in your action file and avoid mixing the two different methods.

Comment: Have you not read and "understood" the question? Your answer is incorrect; that's not what the question is about.